# How to produce documentation for vars only with JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, documentation

I have javascript file which contains a lot of global vars that are commented, but JSDoc keeps telling there is "Nothing to document, exiting".

Here is a sample:

```
/**
 * Name of the clients list
 * @type String
 * @final
 */
var CLIENTS_LIST_NAME = "Client";
```

Is there a way to generate documentation for such a .js file?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using my old Perl-based project named JSDoc.pm. I would recommend for you to upgrade to my newer project named JsDoc Toolkit. The syntax of the newer project is mostly a superset of the tags used in the older project, but have a look at the [wiki on the JsDoc Toolkit project](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/w/list) for a complete list of all the supported tags.

The following will work in JsDoc Toolkit:

```
/**
 * Name of the clients list
 * @type String
 * @constant
 */
var CLIENTS_LIST_NAME = "Client";
```